# creating a download link with PHP

Tags: php

I was reading PHP Solutions and came across these lines of code which confused me, and it would be great if someone could help me figure out the meaning.

```
// define error page
$error = 'http://localhost/phpsols/error.php';
// define the path to the download folder
$filepath = 'C:/xampp/htdocs/phpsols/images/';

$getfile = NULL;

// block any attempt to explore the filesystem
if (isset($_GET['file']) && basename($_GET['file']) == $_GET['file']) {
    $getfile = $_GET['file'];
} else {
    header("Location: $error");
    exit;
}
```

On the 7th line of codes, why would `basename($_GET['file'])` not equal to `$_GET['file']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If someone passed something like `http://example.com/file.txt` or `path/file.txt` or `../../../../etc/hosts` to `$_GET['file']` then the basename would not match.

`basename($file) == $file` will only be true when a value with no path (just a file name) is given.

Comment: Hi drew, thanks for the answer! Just one more follow up question: on the second line of code it is already specified which folder to look into, wouldn't it be theoretically safe already? When i tried `download.php?file=.../index.php`, the file would not show

Comment: The `..` could still be used to traverse downward because `C:/xampp/htdocs/phpsols/images/` with `$_GET['file'] = '../../../../windows/system32/file` would resolve down to `C:/` + whatever path was after the dots.

Comment: so `$_GET['file'] = '../../../../windows/system32/file` will become `C:/windows/system32/file` ?

Comment: Correct.  Because `../` means go up one directory from the current path.  Check out [path traversal](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Path_Traversal) on OWASP for detailed examples.

Answer (score 0):

> On the 7th line of codes, why would basename($_GET['file']) not equal to $_GET['file']?

Because `$_GET['file']` included path separator characters.